# Из-за DebugActiveProcess зависает вся система!

Tags: c++builder, отладка, c++, многопоточность

После использования `DebugActiveProcess()` раз в несколько секунд подвисает вся сисетма.
Процесс, к которому подключаюсь, не системный!
Не могу разобрать, в чем проблема.

Comment: А вы вовремя вызываете `DebugActiveProcessStop()`?

Comment: Нет, мне нужно, чтобы процесс находился в замороженном состоянии!
Я использую DebugActiveProcess() для заморозки всех потоков процесса, а не для отладки.

Comment: @cuvunusij: Возможно, вам нужно запустить цикл обработки отладочных сообщений, чтобы сообщить системе, что вы таки отлаживаете процесс. 

Гляньте [сюда](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger), возможно, найдёте что-нибудь по теме.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо DebugActiveProcess попробуйте OpenProcess, перечислить все потоки и сделать SuspendThread. Сдается мне, подвисание возникает на перечислении процессов каким-то системным процессом.